# How to upload multiple images to node sever and mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb

Hi guys so i have a project with react and mongodb. User will have to register and login in order to access the app. After user login they have a form with (name, number, and images) to input. I have a problem regarding the images. Previosly im able to uplaod images but i want to change the way i upload the image because deployment issues.

Previously im using form with action:`http://localhost:3001/regstration`, i want to change the method with append.file, but its not working. BTW i have a folder called images in root server folder.

Form.js

```
const Form = () => {

   
    Axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
  

    const { emailLog, setEmailLog } = useContext(EmailUser);
    const { userData, setUserData } = useContext(UserData);

    let navigate = useNavigate();

    const userExpire = () => {
      Axios.get('http://localhost:3001/login')
      .then((response)=> {
        if(response.data.loggedIn === true) {
          setEmailLog(response.data.email.email);
          console.log(response);
        } else {
          navigate("/home" , {replace : true});
        }
      });
    };

    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();

      const data = new FormData();
      data.append('pdfFiles', userData.myFile);
      
      Axios.post('http://localhost:3001/registration', {
        headers : {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        },
          email : emailLog,
          CompanyName : userData.cName,
          Address : userData.Address,
          Phone :userData.phoneNumber,
          PresidentName : userData.presidentName,
          ManagerEmail : userData.managerEmail,
          ManagerPhone : userData.managerPhone,
          PICEmail : userData.picEmail,
          PICPhone : userData.picPhone,
          EstablishedDate : userData.date,
          ChoiceBusiness : userData.mainBusiness,
          EmployeeNumber : userData.employeeNumber,
          NumberOfCustomer : userData.numberOfCustomer,
          Attachments : data
        })
        .then(() => {
          setTimeout(() => navigate("/home"), 1000);

        });
    }
   
   
    useEffect(() => {
      userExpire();
    }, [])
  
    
  return (
    <div className='form'>
      <Appbar />
        <h2 style={{textAlign: "center", marginTop : "20px"}}>Supplier Data</h2>
    <form className='formForm' method='POST' encType='multipart/form-data' action='#' onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    <div>
      <input className='inputForm' type='email' value={emailLog} name='email' onChange={(e) => {
          setUserData(e.target.value) }} />
      <input className='inputForm' type='text' placeholder='Company Name' name="CompanyName" value={userData.cName}  onChange={(e) => {
          setUserData({...userData, cName : e.target.value})}}/>
      <input className='inputForm' type='text' placeholder='Address' name="Address" value={userData.Address} onChange={(e) => {
           setUserData({...userData, Address : e.target.value})}} />
      <input className='inputForm' type='tel' placeholder='Phone Number' name="Phone" value={userData.phoneNumber} onChange={(e) => {
          setUserData({...userData, phoneNumber : e.target.value})}}  />
      <input className='inputForm' type='text' placeholder='President Director Name' name="PresidentName" value={userData.presidentName} onChange={(e) => {
          setUserData({...userData, presidentName : e.target.value})}} />
      <input className='inputForm' type='email' placeholder='Manager Email' name="ManagerEmail" value={userData.managerEmail} onChange={(e) => {
           setUserData({...userData, managerEmail : e.target.value})}}  />
      <input className='inputForm' type='tel'  placeholder='Manager Phone' name="ManagerPhone" value={userData.managerPhone} onChange={(e) => {
          setUserData({...userData, managerPhone : e.target.value})}} />
      <input className='inputForm' type='email'  placeholder='PIC Email' name="PICEmail" value={userData.picEmail} onChange={(e) => {
          setUserData({...userData, picEmail : e.target.value})}} />
      <input className='inputForm' type='tel'  placeholder='PIC Phone' name="PICPhone" value={userData.picPhone} onChange={(e) => {
          setUserData({...userData, picPhone : e.target.value})}} />
      <input className='inputForm' type='date' pattern="\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}" placeholder='Date' name="EstablishedDate" value={userData.date} onChange={(e) => {
         setUserData({...userData, date : e.target.value})}} />
          
        <select multiple className='selectBox1' name='ChoiceBusiness' onChange={(e) => {
            setUserData({...userData, mainBusiness : e.target.value})}} >
                  <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Choose Main Business...</option>
                  <option value="Software License">Software License</option>
                  <option value="IT Services & Consulting">IT Services & Consulting</option>
                  <option value="IT Outsourcing">IT Outsourcing</option>
                  <option value="Hardware">Hardware</option>
                  <option value="General Trading">General Trading</option>
                  <option value="Others">Others</option>
        </select>

        <FormBootstrap.Select className='selectBox'  name='EmployeeNumber' onChange={(e) => {
            setUserData({...userData, employeeNumber : e.target.value})}}>
            <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Choose Employee Number...</option>
            <option value="1-50">1-50</option>
            <option value="51-100">51-100</option>
            <option value="101-250">101-250</option>
            <option value="251-500">251-500</option>
            <option value="500+">500+</option>
        </FormBootstrap.Select>

        
      <input className='inputForm' type="text"  placeholder='Number of Customer' name="NumberOfCustomer" value={userData.numberOfCustomer} onChange={(e) => {
          setUserData({...userData, numberOfCustomer : e.target.value})}} />

        <FormBootstrap.Group controlId="formFileMultiple" className="mb-3" style={{width : "300px", marginLeft: "15px"}}>
            <FormBootstrap.Control type="file" multiple name='pdfFiles'  onChange={(e) => {
                setUserData({...userData, myFile : e.target.files})}} />
            <FormBootstrap.Label><small><i>*Please make sure to input the right files</i></small></FormBootstrap.Label>
        </FormBootstrap.Group>

      
        </div>
        <button className='btnSubmit' type='submit'> Submit</button>
    </form>
    </div>
  )
}


export default Form
```

Context :

```
import { createContext, useState } from "react"
export const UserData = createContext();
export default function UserDataProvider({ children }) {
    const [ userData , setUserData ] = useState({
        cName : "",
        Address : "",
        phoneNumber : "",
        presidentName : "",
        managerEmail : "",
        managerPhone : "",
        picEmail : "",
        picPhone : "",
        date: "",
        mainBusiness : [],
        employeeNumber : "",
        numberOfCustomer : "",
        myFile : []
      });

  return (
    <UserData.Provider value={{ userData, setUserData }}>
     {children}
    </UserData.Provider>
  );
}
```

backend :

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, 'images')
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, Date.now() +  path.extname(file.originalname))
    }
});

app.post("/registration", upload.array('pdfFiles', 20), async (req, res) => {

     data = new DataModel({
        //  email : req.body.email ,
         email : req.body.email,
         CompanyName : req.body.CompanyName,
         Address : req.body.Address,
         PhoneNumber : req.body.Phone,
         PresidentName : req.body.PresidentName,
         ManagerEmail : req.body.ManagerEmail,
         ManagerPhone : req.body.ManagerPhone,
         PICEmail : req.body.PICEmail,
         PICPhone : req.body.PICPhone,
         EstablishedDate : req.body.EstablishedDate,
         MainBusiness : req.body.ChoiceBusiness,
         EmployeeNumber : req.body.EmployeeNumber,
         NumberOfCustomer : req.body.NumberOfCustomer,
         Attachments : req.files
        })
    
        
    await data.save();
    res.json(data);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are passing an `Object` as `Formdata`, which is wrong since `Formdata` is a special object. You are also passing data as config & config as data to `axios.post` method, so please the read MDN and Axios docs before asking question here.

Here is example how to send a multi-form request

```
const formdata = new FormData()
formdata.append('pdfFiles', userData.myFile)
formdata.append('email', emailLog)
formdata.append('CompanyName', userData.cName)
// ........
Axios.post('http://localhost:3001/registration', formdata)
// no need to set headers, axios will automatically do it for you.
```

You can also skip calling `.append` by passing `ref` of your form.

```
const formdata = new FormData(regFormRef.current)
formdata.append('addtional_pdfFiles', userData.myFile)
Axios.post('http://localhost:3001/registration', formdata)
```